# axios.create is sharing defaults, is that normal?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to create 2 axios clients, but they seem to be sharing headers. My code is as follows:

```
var client1 = axios.create();
var client2 = axios.create();

client2.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 123;

console.log(client1.defaults.headers.common);
console.log(client2.defaults.headers.common);
```

And both have the `Authorization` header set to `123`.

https://jsfiddle.net/yebqu22d/

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That should be expected. And exactly what `defaults` means.

Update:

In my opinion, `client1.defaults`, `client2.defaults` and even `axios.defaults` point to the same reference. No matter which one you changed, it shares the value to others.

But it's possible to have specify config for each instance by `create`. Check below:

```
var client1 = axios.create({
        headers: {
        common: {
            Authorization: 123
        }
      }
});
var client2 = axios.create();

//client2.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 123;

console.log(client1.defaults.headers.common);
console.log(client2.defaults.headers.common);
```

Comment: What's the point of the create method then? I'm trying to get 2 different instances of an axios client, that's not what it does? I'm setting defaults on `client2`, not `axios` and not `client1`.

Comment: Thanks for your update. My issue is that I need to set the header in the future after receiving a response. I guess I'll just have to re-create the client at that time.

Comment: Maybe you would try with `client2.headers = { Authorization: 123 }` instead of `client2.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 123;`

Comment: Thanks Howard, that doesn't seem to work. Not a problem, I'll figure something out. I did find this, it appears that this is a bug: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/385

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug with axios: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/385